# sharing picture is not coming

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to share the post in TextView. I used main_menu.xml for this. But the picture does not show in the upper left corner. Why do you think this error?

Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main_menu.xml

(picture extension png)

```
<Menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    xmlsn:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/share_button"
        android:title="Share"
        app.showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/a"
        
/>
</Menu>
```

[image]

Comment: Help me +++++++++

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **fragment** you could add the menu the following way:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NotNull final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NotNull final MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.share_button) {
        // do something when menu button is selected
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And if you are using **Activity** `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` is not needed.

Comment: my problem is not java. the problem is not showing the picture i attached on home screen

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following code helps....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:title="Cart"
        android:id="@+id/item_cart"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_overflow"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24"
        app:showAsAction="always">

        <menu>

            <item android:title="Account"
                android:id="@+id/item_account"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_circle"
                app:showAsAction="always"/>

            <item android:title="Share"
                android:id="@+id/item_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_share_24"/>

            <item android:title="Rate this App"
                android:id="@+id/item_rate"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_half_24"/>

            <item android:title="Check for Update"
                android:id="@+id/item_update"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_update_24"/>

        </menu>

    </item>

</menu>
```

what I have done is, put a menu inside another one